# No display after plugging in HDMI to new PC?

Tags: display, gpu, desktop-computer

I plugged in my display into my new PC HDMI, but the display won't detect any signal. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was, I plugged the display into the **motherboard** HDMI, not **GPU** HDMI. Plugging the cable into the motherboard meant the display was going to recieve data from the **CPU iGPU** (which was disabled), not the main graphics card. One extra note, the GPU HDMI input occasionally has dust covers like [these](https://www.datapro.net/images/ZZDCHDMI_large.jpg).